# Resource id#7 shows instead of page title

Tags: php, mysql

I want the Video title to be displayed on top of every page title instead of that it shows Resource id#7. i have even used  mysql fetch assoc but the same result happens Resouce id #7

here is the code:

```
<?php
require( "./inc/connect.inc.php");
$video_id="";
$videoid = $_GET['videoid'];
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id='$videoid'");
if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 1) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)) {
$video_id = mysql_query("SELECT video_id FROM videos WHERE video_id='$video_id'");
$page_title = mysql_query("SELECT video_title FROM videos WHERE video_id='$video_id'");
echo("<title>$page_title</title>");}}
?>
```

Comment: `$page_title` is a resource. If you want get the contents, you need to `fetch` it.

Comment: btw, you just need to use the `$row`. No need to run more query to do that.

Comment: please elaborate via code

Comment: @SummonaChefina StackOverflow isn't a coding service. We'll answer your questions, but we wont do the work for you. The comments should be everything you need to know to solve this.

Comment: @KhorneHoly i am extremely sorry for that but i just wanted a bit explanation

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the fetched row - no need to send the query again in the loop

```
<?php
require( "./inc/connect.inc.php");
$videoid = (int) $_GET['videoid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id='$videoid'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $page_title = $row['video_title'];
    echo("<title>$page_title</title>");
}
?>
```

Btw. mysql_* is deprecated and using it with a modern PHP version would result at least with an warning (newer ones shouldn't have the mysql extension and an error would be raised..) You should use PDO or mysqli

Comment: it didn't worked. the page title this time was the one i gave in my header file.

Comment: If the page_title contains the wrong value, the $_GET var contains the wrong value, or your database contains the wrong value..

Comment: i am confused now .

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise looking (at least) at filter_input() [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) - you should **never** use $_GET values directly in SQL like that as you open yourself up to [injection attacks](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: ... and you don't protect yourself from sql injection with `filter_input`.